# How to diagnose a knocking sound that I hear when the car is running?

Tags: honda, wheels, accord, noise

My car is a 2002 Honda Accord V6. For 2 days now, I'm hearing a sound like "dug dug dug dug dug dug...." as the car starts to move. I think the sound is coming somewhere from the driver side front wheel. The sound started happening after the car skid twice on snow. The traction control system kicked in both of the times when the car skid. The sound stops when the car comes to a complete stop. The sound was not there when I rev'd the engine with the car parked and the hood open. The interval between the "dug dug" reduces as the car speed increases.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: If it's still cold (and I assume it is up in Washington State), you probably have some ice/snow stuck inside one of the wheels. Check the back side of your wheels closely.

Comment: If no snow in the wheel, go to a car park and drive in circles, left and right. If the noise gets worse in one direction, it's the CV joint on the opposite side to the turn.

Comment: I too thought it was snow initially. It has become warm now (upper 40s-lower 50s). All the snow in the ground has melted. But I'm still hearing the noise. I'll try to notice if the noise gets worse if I turn.

Answer (score 1):

CV joint. I  had a older Honda accord that did the same thing. Best way that I found to check them was just look at the boots that cover them to see if they are in one piece and also try and see if the shaft has any play in it. I think it was told before you can drive it and turn both ways and listen for the noise . Some of it depends on how bad they are worn.